# How to use files content (image/pdf) form IPFS (basically downloading ipfs images/pdf)

Tags: node.js, encoding, ipfs

I am implementing `Kubo RPC API` in Node JS to upload files to IPFS, Uploads works, but when I try to get content of file using `ifps.cat(CID)` it returns may be plain text, stream or chunks (may be encoded, I don't know which type of encoding is it.).

My question is how do I convert this data to a readable image or pdf, below code create image which is unreadable or pdf which is empty.

**node JS Code:**

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/cat?arg=QmYjChbAEthEYz7qiR8XHHFS9uRZcMsfZVukpAcCF4q6xw')
  .then(async function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    fs.writeFile("./myfile.png",response.data, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.status(200).send("files saved.");
    });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
```

**Console log:**
[image]

**Image created by:**
[image]

Comment: In that screenshot the initial header with "Qm..." is an IPFS object header, which is sent over with `ipfs.get`, you'd want `ipfs.cat`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but may be I was unable to clear the things, data return by API is correct but encoded, I just want to decode it (like binary decode or utf8 etc. I don't know). my question was about how do I decode or collect these data to make files and images

Comment: `ipfs.cat` returns the file *exactly* as it was when it was added to IPFS, without any encoding. If there's encoding, it would have had to have been encoded when it was added. If I do `ipfs add myimage.png` then do `ipfs cat cidofmyimage > myimage2.png` then `myimage.png` and `myimage2.png` will be identical.

Comment: @MubashirFarooq for whatever reason I can't retrieve the CID you're sharing, it's not available whenever I go to look at it. If you give me a CID that's not working for you, that's available (you can back up the data to web3.storage or something to do that), I'll investigate and might be able to get you a solid answer.